# Get preceding sibling for CSS selector

Tags: css, excel, vba, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest

In a code for QHarr at this link
[Retrieving all Excel file links from a webpage with Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53443254/retrieving-all-excel-file-links-from-a-webpage-with-excel-vba/53443876#53443876)

```
Public Sub Links()
Dim sResponse As String, html As HTMLDocument, list As Object, i As Long

With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    .Open "GET", "https://www.jpx.co.jp/markets/public/short-selling/index.html", False
    .setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
    .send
    sResponse = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
End With

Set html = New HTMLDocument
With html
    .body.innerHTML = sResponse
    Set list = html.querySelectorAll("[href$='.xls']")
End With
For i = 0 To list.Length - 1
    Debug.Print Replace$(list.item(i), "about:", "https://www.jpx.co.jp")
Next
End Sub
```

I am trying to use CSS selector in another way .. and I used this
img[title='Excel']
But this returns objects not the link preceding this selector
The question is how to refer to the preceding tag which is a tag ..?
[image]

Comment: Specify the a tag having a specific child: `a img[title=‘Excel’]`?

Comment: Thanks a lot. But this returns a list of objects in the code

Comment: Another xpath would be `"//a[img[@title='Excel']]"`.

Comment: That's working fine too. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do parent element selection with css selectors in vba (you are looking at a parent child relationship, not sibling). CSS cascades down. Additionally, there is something called [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) which comes into play.

You need to write a selector which targets what you want or switch to selenium and use xpath (though not sure how much functionality is supported in selenium basic xpath implementation). I show an appropriate two CSS selector methods below and an XPath option.

You can use the same principle of attribute and $ operator and target the src

```
[src$='xls.png']
```

So,

```
Set list = html.querySelectorAll("[src$='xls.png']")
Debug.Print list.item(0).src
```

You could also use:

```
img[title=Excel]
```

---

Using xpath and selenium basic to find parents

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetParents()
    Dim d As WebDriver, elements As Object, element As Object
    Set d = New ChromeDriver
    Const URL = "https://www.jpx.co.jp/markets/public/short-selling/index.html"
    With d
        .get URL

        Set elements = .FindElementsByXPath("//img[@title='Excel']/parent::a")
        For Each element In elements
            Debug.Print element.Attribute("href")
        Next
         Stop
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am seeking to know how to deal with preceding sibling

Comment: You can't do preceeding sibling with css selectors in vba. CSS cascades down. You need to write a selector which targets what you want or switch to selenium and use xpath (though not sure how much functionality is supported in vba xpath implementation)

Comment: So how can I use XPath in that case .. in excel vBA?

Comment: I'm confused as I think you want a descendant. Do you want the img after the a?

Comment: No I need the same results as your code do (the links) >> so I need the links before the img tag but relying on the img tag css selector ...

Comment: Thank you very much for awesome help